# Pass List<String> from controller to view in Scala/Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to pass a List object from a controller to a view in Scala/Play Framework.

I cannot get the view (html) to compile.  It does not like how I have the view set -- it gives me this error:

```
[error] C:\WebDev\git\PlayAuthenticate\app\views\profile\editprofile.scala.html:
130: Expected ')' but found 'EOF'
[error] }
[error]  ^
[error] (compile:twirlCompileTemplates) Twirl compilation failed
```

Here is the first line of code in the view:

```
@(profileForm: Form[Application.ProfileRegister], servicesList: java.util.List[Service], profile: Profile, servicesSelected: List[String])
```

I am guessing the `servicesSelected: List[String]` is incorrect.

Here is my function in the controller:

```
public Result openProfile(String name) {
    Form<ProfileRegister> profileEntry = form(ProfileRegister.class).bindFromRequest();
    List<Service> services = Service.find.all();
    // Find profile and display...
    Profile profile = Profile.findByName(name);
    // Grab the current services...
    String currentServices = profile.services;
    List<String> selectedServices = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(currentServices.split(",")));
    return ok(showprofile.render(profileEntry, services, profile, selectedServices));
}
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: From what I can see you are passing a `java.util.List` in your controller code to the view, but the view expects a `scala.collection.immutable.List` for the `servicesSelected` argument. But that doesn't explain to compilation error in line 130 of your view.

Comment: @PermaFrost - Line 130 is the last line in my view -- the closing of the `main{}` tag in Scala.  What is the correct syntax to send the `scala.collection.immutable.List`?  Or is there another way to get an array of strings to the Scala view?  Thanks!

Comment: Well, just try declaring `java.util.List[String]` (exactly like this, with the package prefix) in your view constructor and don't change anything in the controller code to see if that fixes the problem. I am just wondering whether the error is really caused by this.

Comment: Changed to servicesSelected: java.util.List[String], but same error.  When I remove that parameter (from both the controller and view), it compiles without errors.  I add those back, it causes the error.

Comment: Can you paste the entire view in the form that causes the error (with the last argument included)?

Comment: @PermaFrost - thanks for your help.  I started up my environment today and everything worked.  I cannot tell you what happened.  Thanks again.